# Dot Net Web API (minimal) endpoint not handling request from Vue3 app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vuejs3, single-page-application

I'm using Asp Dot Net 6 Web API with minimal API endpoints instead of Controllers. When I run my Vue3 app within Visual Studio using a proxy, the Vue3 app loads successfully. However, if I try and hit an API endpoint, Dot Net does not handle it. Instead, the Vue3 app simply renders.

Here's an example `Program.cs` file:

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/api/my-endpoint", () =>
{
    return "Hello world from API";
});

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSpa(spaBuilder =>
    {
        spaBuilder.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
    });
}

app.Run();
```

How to replicate:

- In Visual Studio, hit F5 to fire up the app, browser goes to http://localhost:5000
- I see the standard Vue3 app (good)
- If I go to http://localhost:5000/api/my-endpoint, it still renders the Vue3 app instead of rendering `Hello world from API`

This means that my Vue3 app will not be able to hit any endpoints that are handled by Dot Net. Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, now ... did you find any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add them in your vue.config.js as proxy.
something like this.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '^/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true
      },
    }
  }
}
```

check this [Article](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/vue-js-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-a562bad965eb) for more info.